# Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in

Tags: php, memcached

For this line

```
$MEM = new Memcache;
```

I get this error "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in...".  I put this in my php.ini and still no success.

```
extension=memcache.so
```

Does that mean my webhost doesn't have memcached? Do i have to download memcached and uploaded anything to the server for it to work?

Comment: yes, did you check : "php -i | grep -i memcache" (without the quotes) to see if it's there?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those commands, what do i do to see to that?

Comment: sorry about that, you have a Linux? Windows? that command can be executed in a shell command (command line if you prefer)

Comment: You mention a web host. Are you using the right `php.ini` or did you just create a `php.ini` somewhere? The web server only reads one particular `php.ini`; any other `php.ini` won't make any difference.

Comment: Also, did you restart the web server after adding the line to your `php.ini`?

Comment: This is confusing, I want to use memcached to hold php variables.  I thought this would have to be on my web host so other users of my website can use their RAM for memcache to hold certain variables on my website.

Comment: in order to accomplish this, you have to make sure it's installed. what is your webhost? linux or windows?

Comment: my web host is justhost.com lol, i guess i should contact them.

Comment: go there: http://webhostinggeeks.com/user-reviews/index2.php?view=all&item_id=29&sort=notuseful&pg_orig=3&order=DESC&PHPSESSID= and search for: memcache

Answer (score 5):

Here's the reply from JustHost

```
John H.: [6:28:55 PM] Welcome to our real-time support chat. My name is John H. Please be patient, as I may be assisting multiple customers. Also, please provide your main domain name, and a brief description of the problem or request. Thank you.
ME: [6:28:55 PM] is memcache enable for share host?
[6:30:01 PM] hi
John H.: [6:30:31 PM] Let me see what I can find out for you. Just one moment please.
ME: [6:30:37 PM] thanks
John H.: [6:41:04 PM] I have asked an L2, and am waiting for a response. sorry for the delay.
ME: [6:41:39 PM] no problem
John H.: [6:41:49 PM] no, it's not enabled.
[6:41:52 PM] we don't support it
ME: [6:42:11 PM] ok thank you
```

I would recommend to use the chat feature next time you or will order a new shared host and ask the representative if they have memcached enable.